# How to override/customize ALL server errors in Django and Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, exception, error-handling, django-rest-framework

I have a ViewSet:

```py
...
from handlers import specific_exception_handler...
...

class SomeViewSet(GenericViewSet):
    """
    Some custom generic viewset
    """
    queryset = SomeModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SomeSerializer
    parser_classes = (ParserClassThatReadSpecificXML,)
    renderer_classes = (RendererClassThatConvertResponseIntoSpecificXML,)

    def get_exception_handler(self):
        return specific_exception_handler_function_that_return_specific_xml_format_error

    @action(methods=['post'], detail=False, url_path='some_url', url_name='some_url')
    def register(self, request, format=None):

        some_variable = request.data.get('some_value', None)

        if not some_variable:
            raise ValueError

        return Response(data=some_variable, content_type="text/xml; charset=shift_jis")
```

I have a render:

```py
...
import xmltodict

class RendererClassThatConvertResponseIntoSpecificXML(BaseRenderer):
    media_type = 'text/xml'
    format = 'txt'
    charset = 'shift_jis'

    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        # return data as non utf-8 xml string
        return xmltodict.unparse(data).encode("shift_jis")
```

I have a custom error handler:

```py
...
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler

def specific_exception_handler_function_that_return_specific_xml_format_error(exc, context):

    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    if response is not None:
        status_code = response.status_code
    else:
        status_code = status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

    specific_data_that_will_be_converted_into_xml_by_render = {'ERROR_STATUS': status_code}
    headers = {'Retry-After': '300'}

    return Response(data, content_type='text/xml; charset=shift_jis', status=status_code, headers=headers)
```

Problem:

If View's `raise ValueError` will be raised I get my custom XML formatted error message.

1. But if some exception will be happened inside render, there is appears Django's standard `500 Server Error` message
2. If I will try to access outside View , there is appears Django's standard `404 Server Error` message again

I want to show my custom XML error anytime.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here is still no answer, so I will try to answer by myself

how I finally did it:

1. changed my custom error handlers:

```py
...
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler
from rest_framework import status
from django.http import HttpResponse
...

# ex-specific_exception_handler_function_that_return_specific_xml_format_error
def inside_view_occurred_error_handler(exc, context):

    if isinstance(exc, rest_framework.exceptions.NotAuthenticated):
        # do custom action for NotAuthenticated
    elif isinstance(exc, rest_framework.exceptions.PermissionDenied):
        # do custom action for PermissionDenied
    elif ...
        # do actions for other drf errors if needed

    # set status (for example 500)
    status = status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
    # set body
    body='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="shift_jis"?><a attr="error">エラー</a>'.encode('shift_jis')

    # create response
    r = HttpResponse(body, status=status, content_type='text/xml; charset=shift_jis')

    # add headers
    r['Retry-After'] = '3000'

    return r

def outside_view_400_error_handler(request, exception):

    # set status
    status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
    # set body
    body='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="shift_jis"?><a attr="error_400">エラー400</a>'.encode('shift_jis')

    # create response
    r = HttpResponse(body, status=status, content_type='text/xml; charset=shift_jis')

    # add headers
    r['Retry-After'] = '3000'

    return r

def outside_view_500_error_handler(request):

    # set status
    status = status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
    # set body
    body='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="shift_jis"?><a attr="error_500">エラー500</a>'.encode('shift_jis')

    # create response
    r = HttpResponse(body, status=status, content_type='text/xml; charset=shift_jis')

    # add headers
    r['Retry-After'] = '3000'

    return r

def outside_view_404_error_handler(request, exception):

    # set status
    status = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
    # here is no body

    # create response
    r = HttpResponse(status=status, content_type='text/xml; charset=shift_jis')

    return r
```

2. added handlers in urls.py

```py
handler400 = 'application.handlers.outside_view_400_error_handler'
handler404 = 'application.handlers.outside_view_404_error_handler'
handler500 = 'application.handlers.outside_view_500_error_handler'
```

And now if `DEBUG = False` Django responding anytime with custom responses.